# Objective C - Import cocos2d game - C++ Errors

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i'm actually trying to do a launcher of cocos2d game in Objective C (for an iOS app).

But i'm having a lot of errors, and don't really know C++ well (there is lot C++ code in the cocos2d game, which I didn't create).

To describe how I integrated the game (maybe did mistakes) :

- Add the xcodeproj of cocos game in my application
- Add the cocos as a target dependancy.
- In build settings, set Always search user path to "YES".
- Change "Compile source as" in "Objective-C++"
- Add .mm extensions to files which will call the cocos2d game functions.

Are all this steps necessary ?

I now getting new errors in my code, like :

```
return [self drawInRect:rect withZFont:font lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
```

"Cannot initialize a parameter of type "UITextAlignment" (aka 'NSTextAlignment") with an rvalue of type 'anonymous enum at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/De‌​veloper/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea‌​ders/UIStringDrawing.h:40:1>.

So I should cast the value, but I don't really want to change all my previous code to make it works..
Is there a way to avoid that?

And is there some steps I missed in the integration, or maybe future advices :).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only left out the essence of the error message. With an rvalue of **what** type?

Comment: rvalue of type '<anonymous enum at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIStringDrawing.h:40:1>'. Don't know if it helps...

Comment: Thanks, it does help. Well, it's kind of a stupid error message. You should be able to initialize one enum type with another... You should not be getting this error in fact.

Comment: C++ is far more strict about typing than C is. There are going to be things that work fine when compiling code as C that will not work when compiling the same code as C++. It's just kind of a fact of life.  I often find that I need to add casts when making this change. The other thing to know is that using C-style casts in C++ is kind of "cheating". If you want to do C++ casting "right" you should familiarize yourself with this: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: But those files are written in Objective C. I just want to import the game, use 1 file to launch it. But the rest of my application is in Obj-C..

Comment: If you are compiling them as C++, you have to follow C++ rules.

Comment: They are defined as "Objective C Source" file. Is there a way to compile them in ObjC and the game + some files in C++ ?

Comment: To use c++ code inside your objective-c classes, change extension of your objective-c file from *.m to *.mm. Then you will be able to use c++ code.